# How to Instantiate Joda DateTime from TimeZone String ID and Epoch

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, jodatime

I am taking a look at the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) library.  I am trying to figure out how to construct a DateTime object given an epoch time stamp and a timezone.  I am hoping that allows me to find the day of week, how of day, etc for that epoch time, in that time zone.  However I am unsure how to pass the DateTimeZone to the DateTime constructor.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.Instant;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

        DateTimeZone tz = new DateTimeZone( "America/New_York" );

        DateTime dt = new DateTime( epoch, tz );

        System.out.println( dt );
    }

}
```

I tried the above hardcoded example of "America/New_York", but got this from the compiler.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ javac -cp "joda-time-2.2.jar:." TimeZoneTest.java
    TimeZoneTest.java:12: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone is abstract; cannot be instantiated
    DateTimeZone tz = new DateTimeZone( "America/New_York" );
                      ^
    1 error
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get a time zone from an ID, you use [`DateTimeZone.forID`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forID%28java.lang.String%29):

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
```

As an aside, I don't think "epoch" is a good name for your variable - it's really "seconds since the Unix epoch". Additionally, I don't see why you're dividing by 1000... [the relevant constructor for `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long,%20org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) takes a time zone and the *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch... so you can pass the value returned from `System.currentTimeMillis()` directly.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the answer, works perfectly and points me in the right direction (ie reading the docs more thoroughly :).